# How to make my application independent phone language

Tags: android

i build new application with simple login activity with firebase when i install on phone with english language it work perfectly.
but when i change phone language to arabic it dosen't work.
all data entered was in english language.Any ideas?!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for UI design it makes difference if your user phone is using right to left language or left to right language
if this is the case you should decide you want your app adapt changes or be fixed 
for example you can use `layout_marginLeft` instead of using `layout_marginStart`

but for preferences activity you cannot change layout direction in easy way

Comment: is UI design affect on functionality of application!
because code work perfect on emulator but not work in real phone

Comment: it says "getServiceInstance failed!"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support arabic your app should support RTL. 
you need to change all your layouts where ever you are using left and right to start and end. 
Also you need add textAlignment property to textviews.